# How to carrying over values for missing dates in time series using last value windows analytical functions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, window-functions, recursive-query

How to carrying over values for missing dates postcode/indicator_category to create full monthly time series. Im trying to use last_value to carry over values but not able to make it. Is my approach correct? Any help would by highly appreciated.

Example given a table:

```
    create table test.indicator_data(
      postcode text, 
      month_ts date, 
      indicator_cat integer,
      measure double precision);
```

INSERT INTO value to indicator_data table

```
    INSERT INTO test.indicator_data 
    VALUES
    ('sw5', '2017-07-01', 2, 99212.231),
    ('sw5', '2018-02-01', 2, 232.215),
    ('sw5', '2017-11-01', 3, 1523.2576),
    ('sw5', '2017-12-01', 3, 152.16),
    ('sw5', '2018-02-01', 3, 142.981),
    ('sw5', '2018-07-01', 3 , 142.1361),
    ('sw5 9', '2018-03-01', 2, 821.21),
    ('sw5 9', '2018-02-01', 2, 1182.19);
```

INPUT:

| postcode | month_ts | indicator_cat | measure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sw5 | 2017-07-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2018-02-01 | 2 | 232.215 |
| sw5 | 2017-11-01 | 3 | 1523.2576 |
| sw5 | 2017-12-01 | 3 | 152.16 |
| sw5 | 2018-02-01 | 3 | 142.981 |
| sw5 | 2018-07-01 | 3 | 142.1361 |
| sw59 | 2018-03-01 | 2 | 821.21 |
| sw59 | 2018-02-01 | 2 | 1182.19 |

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

| postcode | month_ts | indicator_cat | measure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sw5 | 2017-07-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2017-08-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2017-09-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2017-10-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2017-11-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2017-12-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2018-01-01 | 2 | 99212.231 |
| sw5 | 2018-02-01 | 2 | 232.215 |
| sw5 | 2017-11-01 | 3 | 1523.2576 |
| sw5 | 2017-12-01 | 3 | 152.16 |
| sw5 | 2018-01-01 | 3 | 152.16 |
| sw5 | 2018-02-01 | 3 | 142.981 |
| sw5 | 2018-03-01 | 3 | 142.981 |
| sw5 | 2018-04-01 | 3 | 142.981 |
| sw5 | 2018-05-01 | 3 | 142.981 |
| sw5 | 2018-06-01 | 3 | 142.981 |
| sw5 | 2018-07-01 | 3 | 142.1361 |
| sw59 | 2018-02-01 | 2 | 1182.19 |
| sw59 | 2018-03-01 | 2 | 821.21 |

Tried SOLUTION:

Created Calender table using below procedue:

```
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE PROCEDURE test.fill_calendar(`start_date` DATE, `end_date` DATE)
    BEGIN
      DECLARE `crt_date` DATE;
      SET `crt_date`=start_date;
      WHILE `crt_date` < `end_date` DO
        INSERT INTO calendar VALUES(`crt_date`);
        SET `crt_date` = ADDDATE(`crt_date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
      END WHILE;
    END |
    DELIMITER ;
```

Calling Procedure

```
CALL test.fill_calendar('2017-07-01', '2018-07-01');
```

Query tried to missing dates but its failing to get last_values

```
    select postcode,last_value(postcode) over (order by datefield) from (
    SELECT indicator_data.postcode,calendar.datefield AS date,indicator_data.indicator_cat,indicator_data.measure
    FROM indicator_data RIGHT join calendar ON (DATE(indicator_data.month_ts) = calendar.datefield)
    WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(month_ts)) FROM indicator_data) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(month_ts)) FROM indicator_data))
    GROUP BY date) as test;
```

Comment: Your calendar stops at 2018-06-01 change < to <=? or amend end date

Comment: Month_ts is a date datatype you don't need to use a date function on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the calendar table's resultset with a recursive CTE.
Then do a `LEFT` join of the calendar to the table and use `SUM()` window function to create groups of rows with `null` in `measure`.
Finally use `MAX()` window function to pick the last non-null `measure`:

```
WITH  
  RECURSIVE dates AS (
    SELECT postcode, indicator_cat, MIN(month_ts) month_ts, MAX(month_ts) max_month_ts 
    FROM indicator_data
    GROUP BY postcode, indicator_cat
    UNION ALL
    SELECT postcode, indicator_cat, month_ts + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, max_month_ts 
    FROM dates 
    WHERE month_ts + INTERVAL 1 MONTH <= max_month_ts
  ),
  cte AS (
    SELECT d.postcode, d.month_ts, d.indicator_cat, i.measure,
           SUM(i.measure IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY d.postcode, d.indicator_cat ORDER BY d.month_ts) grp
    FROM dates d LEFT JOIN indicator_data i
    ON (i.postcode, i.indicator_cat, i.month_ts) = (d.postcode, d.indicator_cat, d.month_ts)
  )
SELECT postcode, month_ts, indicator_cat,  
       MAX(measure) OVER (PARTITION BY postcode, indicator_cat, grp) measure   
FROM cte
ORDER BY postcode, indicator_cat, month_ts;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=550819f2643caeacef06cd5e313a90aa).

Answer (score 1):

Recursive CTE could get expected results:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
max_info AS (
  SELECT postcode, indicator_cat, MAX(month_ts) month_ts
  FROM indicator_data
  GROUP BY postcode, indicator_cat
),
fill_info AS (
  SELECT postcode, indicator_cat, month_ts, measure
  FROM indicator_data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT postcode, indicator_cat, month_ts + INTERVAL 1 MONTH month_ts, measure
  FROM fill_info i
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM indicator_data d
    WHERE d.postcode = i.postcode
    AND d.indicator_cat = i.indicator_cat
    AND d.month_ts = i.month_ts + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM max_info m
    WHERE m.postcode = i.postcode
    AND m.indicator_cat = i.indicator_cat
    AND m.month_ts > i.month_ts + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  )
)
SELECT postcode, month_ts, indicator_cat, measure
FROM fill_info
ORDER BY postcode, indicator_cat, month_ts
```